# Strange behavior between functions cut and ifelse in R

Tags: r, r-factor

I am working in `R` with a dataframe composed of a numeric variable and a character variable. My dataframe `DF` looks like this (I add the `dput` version in final part):

```
   a1    b1
1   a 10.15
2   a 25.10
3   a 32.40
4   a 56.70
5   a 89.02
6   b 90.50
7   b 78.53
8   b 98.12
9   b 34.30
10  b 99.75
```

In `DF` the variable `a1` is a group variable and `b1` is a numeric variable. Then the dilem appear. I want to create a new variable named `c1` by using `cut` function and considering the group saved in `a1`. For this reason I combine both functions `ifelse()` and `cut()` in the next line of code:

```
DF$c1=ifelse(DF$a1=="a",
                cut(DF$b1,breaks = c(0,25,50,70,max(DF$b1)),right = TRUE,include.lowest = TRUE),
                ifelse(DF$a1=="b",
                       cut(DF$b1,breaks = c(0,50,max(DF$b1)),right = TRUE,include.lowest = TRUE),NA))
```

The line of code worked fine, but there is a confusing result for he new values created in `c1`. Instead of showing a factor, `cut()` returns integers. Then, I got this result:

```
table(DF$c1,exclude=NULL)

   1    2    3    4 <NA> 
   2    6    1    1    0
```

Despite of creating the breaks, the integers allocated in `c1` change the result. This does not happen when I work without ifelse but in this case I do not agree conditions over the group. For example the next line of code returns this result:

```
DF$c1=cut(DF$b1,breaks = c(0,25,50,70,max(DF$b1)),right = TRUE,include.lowest = TRUE)

table(DF$c1,exclude=NULL)

   [0,25]   (25,50]   (50,70] (70,99.8]      <NA> 
        1         3         1         5         0
```

I would like to know how to solve this behavior between `ifelse()` and `cut()` functions because the returned integers produce differences in the final result. In this example I work only with two groups for `a1` variable but I have a large database with many groups. That is the reason I combine the functions to get different cuts for each group. Also the values for the breaks can change, so including labels in a manual way could be long. Is it possible that the combination of this two functions return the correct labels for each group (factor) instead of integers. The `dput()` version of my dataframe `DF` is the next:

```
DF<-structure(list(a1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b"), b1 = c(10.15, 25.1, 32.4, 56.7, 89.02, 90.5, 78.53, 
98.12, 34.3, 99.75)), .Names = c("a1", "b1"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that both `cut()` output a factor, but that since they have different levels, they are coerced to integer. A solution may be to surround your `cut()` with `as.character()`, thus preserving the levels for coercion, and then `factor()` the whole output:

```
DF$c1=factor(ifelse(DF$a1=="a",
             as.character(cut(DF$b1,breaks = c(0,25,50,70,max(DF$b1)),right = TRUE,include.lowest = TRUE)),
             ifelse(DF$a1=="b",
                    as.character(cut(DF$b1,breaks = c(0,50,max(DF$b1)),right = TRUE,include.lowest = TRUE)),NA)))

DF

   a1    b1        c1
1   a 10.15    [0,25]
2   a 25.10   (25,50]
3   a 32.40   (25,50]
4   a 56.70   (50,70]
5   a 89.02 (70,99.8]
6   b 90.50 (50,99.8]
7   b 78.53 (50,99.8]
8   b 98.12 (50,99.8]
9   b 34.30    [0,50]
10  b 99.75 (50,99.8]
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you sort the factor?

Comment: what do you mean? Sort the rows in the data frame? or the levels?

Comment: When you convert to character, the factor breaks don't line up properly, so when you do means by the c1, the order of the factor is not ordered properly.  Or when you graph using the factor as the x variable, the order is all wrong.

Comment: Ok. You'll need to relevel by adding a `levels` argument to `factor()`. Since we cannot be sure what the exact levels will be, you'll need to tinker around with that, but just adding `DF$c1 <- factor(DF$c1, levels = sort(levels(DF$c1)))` should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

@scoa is right; you're trying to combine two factors with different levels, so your results are getting coerced to integers and you're losing the levels. Here's another approach with a smaller form factor, which will be more scalable.

First, make a named list of all your breaks:

```
breaks <- list('a' = c(0, 25, 50, 70, max(DF$b1)), 'b' = c(0, 50, max(DF$b1)))
breaks

> $a
>     0 25 50 70 99.75 
> $b
>     0 50 99.75
```

Then use `unlist(list(some, factors))` (or in this case, `lapply`), which neatly merges factors, keeping all the levels. (It's sorta magic; it's one of those built-in functionalities that's really not obvious.)

```
DF$c1 <- unlist(lapply(1:length(breaks), 
                   function(x){cut(DF[DF$a1 == names(breaks[x]), 'b1'], 
                                   breaks = breaks[[x]], 
                                   right = TRUE, 
                                   include.lowest = TRUE)}
                   ))
DF

>    a1    b1        c1
> 1   a 10.15    [0,25]
> 2   a 25.10   (25,50]
> 3   a 32.40   (25,50]
> 4   a 56.70   (50,70]
> 5   a 89.02 (70,99.8]
> 6   b 90.50 (50,99.8]
> 7   b 78.53 (50,99.8]
> 8   b 98.12 (50,99.8]
> 9   b 34.30    [0,50]
> 10  b 99.75 (50,99.8]
```

It's ultimately 2 lines of code, and should be robust on a larger, more complicated data set.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but rather an alternativ approach to the overall task.

Because you have "*a large database with many groups [with] different cuts for each group*", it seems to me that a code with many nested `ifelse` soon may get quite messy. Perhaps a matter of taste, but I think that the code would be easier to read and maintain if you store the `breaks` for each group in a separate table instead.

Here's how you might do it using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt_brk <- data.table(grp = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                     brk = c(0, 25, 50, 70, Inf, 0, 50, Inf))
```

Note that I use `Inf` as the upper limit of the breaks, rather than `max(your-values)`

We convert your data frame "DF" to a `data.table` using `setDT`. Then, for each level of "a1" (`by = a1`), we `cut` "b1", using `breaks` from "dt_brk", where "grp" equals "a1" (`dt_brk[grp == a1, brk]`).

```
setDT(DF)[, c1 := as.character(cut(b1, breaks = dt_brk[grp == a1, brk])), by = a1]

DF
#     a1    b1       c1
# 1:   a 10.15   (0,25]
# 2:   a 25.10  (25,50]
# 3:   a 32.40  (25,50]
# 4:   a 56.70  (50,70]
# 5:   a 89.02 (70,Inf]
# 6:   b 90.50 (50,Inf]
# 7:   b 78.53 (50,Inf]
# 8:   b 98.12 (50,Inf]
# 9:   b 34.30   (0,50]
# 10:  b 99.75 (50,Inf]
```